# Background pixelated

Tags: html, css, background, css-gradients

I'm looking for a background effect like this (in pure CSS), how can I do this?

[image: bg]

**(zoomed image)**

[image]

Code:

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  background-color:#3D3D3D;
  display:flex;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:10px auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #868686 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #868686 75%, #868686), linear-gradient(45deg, #868686 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #868686 75%, #868686);
  background-position: 0 0, 51px 51px;
  background-color: #222222;
  background-size: 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is pure CSS solution create 4 `linear-gradients` like this with `repeat-x` and appropriate positioning.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 25px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 50px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 75px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right,    #222 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 100px repeat-x;
}
```

Then repeat `linear-gradient` many many times. Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 25px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 50px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 75px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 100px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 125px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 150px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 175px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 200px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 225px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 250px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 275px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 300px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 325px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 350px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 375px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 400px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 425px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 450px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 475px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 500px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 525px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 550px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 575px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 600px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 625px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 650px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 675px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 700px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 725px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 750px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 775px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 800px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 825px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 850px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 875px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 900px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 925px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 950px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 975px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1000px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1025px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 1050px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1075px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1100px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1125px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 1150px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1175px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1200px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #868686 50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1225px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #222    50%) 0 0 / 50px 1250px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #3d3d3d 50%, #868686 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1275px repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to right, #222    50%, #3d3d3d 50%) 0 0 / 50px 1300px repeat-x;
    /* and so on */
}
```

Of course you can use any programming language or some CSS preprocessor to generate this monster CSS properties.

But to be honest I would use SVG for this thing with 8 squares. Demo:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 40">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#868686"/>
  <rect x="10" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/>
  <rect x="0" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="#222"/>
  <rect x="0" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/>
  <rect x="10" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="#868686"/>
  <rect x="0" y="30" width="10" height="10" fill="#222"/>
  <rect x="10" y="30" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/>
</svg>
```

Demo with SVG (works only in Chrome, you'll need to use external SVG (preferred way) or escape SVG markup):

```css
body {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 40"><rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#868686"/><rect x="10" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/><rect x="0" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/><rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="#222"/><rect x="0" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/><rect x="10" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="#868686"/><rect x="0" y="30" width="10" height="10" fill="#222"/><rect x="10" y="30" width="10" height="10" fill="#3d3d3d"/></svg>') 0 0 / 40px 80px repeat;
}
```

Demo with escaped inline SVG, works everywhere, but less maintainable:

```css
body {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2040%22%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%23868686%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%233d3d3d%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%233d3d3d%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%23222%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%2220%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%233d3d3d%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2220%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%23868686%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%2230%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%23222%22/%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2230%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22%233d3d3d%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E') 0 0 / 40px 80px repeat;
}
```

Comment: @EyWN With a great pleasure!

Comment: SVG is also a great option.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Easier, flexible and more efficient would be using a base64 that you can easily produce with http://www.patternify.com (or something similar). A base64 will be produced that you can implement as a `background-image` URL with a `repeat`.

Option 2: CSS only solution from CSS3 Pie. Adapt your colors as needed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  padding: 100vh 100vw 0 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(63deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
              -webkit-linear-gradient(243deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
              -webkit-linear-gradient(63deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
              -webkit-linear-gradient(243deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
              -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
              -webkit-linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(63deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
              -moz-linear-gradient(243deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
              -moz-linear-gradient(63deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
              -moz-linear-gradient(243deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
              -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
              -moz-linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
  background: linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
              linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
              linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
              linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
              linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
              linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #131313;
  -pie-background: linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px / 20px,
                   linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px / 20px,
                   linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px / 20px,
                   linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px / 20px,
                   linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px) 0 0 / 20px,
                   linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424)
                   0 0 / 20px #131313;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Source: http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the required background but I guess it is simple and easy to use.

```css
div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #868686 10%, #fff 10%);
  background-color: #222222;
}

div.last{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(transparent, #868686 10%, #fff 10%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="last"></div>
```